# send mail to subscriptors in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, sendmail, subscription

I am developing a wbesite with Drupal 6.

I need a subscription block to get emails of visitors. And a module to send some html emails sometime to all of them at a time or for some of them.

What module can I use?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://drupal.org/project/simplenews this module, you can easily customize the template and it have many related modules like Simplenews Scheduler, Simplenews Content Selection, .. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am in favor of 3rd party services that integrate into Drupal for this.

This will take the load off your server and you will have better tools at your disposal for creating the emails.

Mailchimp is a popular one that integrates into Drupal nicely.

http://mailchimp.com/
http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp